# I'm a Malaysian passport holder traveling from Malaysia to Singapore (under vtl lane). Do I need a transit visa for Phnom Penh?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, cambodia, malaysian-citizens

I'm travelling with Malaysia Airline from Kuala Lumpur with a layover in Cambodia for 5 hours. Do I need a transit visa for this?

Comment: There are no VTL flights from KL to Singapore via Phnom Penh.  All VTL flights from KL to Singapore are direct flights.

Comment: Put your exact details in here and see what you get: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm